# Why does cells.find throw a runtime error 91 for searchstrings longer than 1 char?

Tags: excel, vba, find, cell

I'm trying to solve an issue that I've not had with Excel VBA so far.
I've got a couple of sheets in a workbook, whereof only two are of interest - let's call them WS1 and WS2. Both contain one table each filled with text and numbers. Now all I wanted to do is take once cell from WS1 and find the row of the cell with the same content in WS2 as follows (exerpt):

```
Dim temprow as Long
temprow = Worksheets("WS2").Cells.Find(Worksheets("WS1").Cells(1, 1)).Row
```

This works as long as there is only one letter or number in cell(1,1) in WS1. As soon as the content is longer I get a runtime error 91. Next I've tried to eliminate WS1 as follows:

```
Dim temprow as Long
temprow = Worksheets("WS2").Cells.Find("randomtext").Row
```

But the same issue arises with radomtext. "A" works fine, "randomtext" causes a runtime error 91.
I've also tried using the set command, also to no avail... Writing content in cells however is possible via VBA for both WS1 and WS2

I'm sort of surprised that the behaviour is related to the length of the string that I look for as though it's some sort of memory error... Does anybody have an idea what else I could try?

Comment: The error means that the find is failing. Either the text is not in the search range, or one of the options for Find (which are retained in between find operations whether done in VBA or the UI) is preventing a match. You should always specify **all** the arguments to be safe.

Comment: Specifying all arguments did the trick - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can negate this error by checking that a suitable range reference is available i.e.

```
Dim temprow as Long
Dim tempRng as Range
Set tempRng = Worksheets("WS2").Cells.Find(Worksheets("WS1").Cells(1, 1).Value)
If Not tempRng is Nothing then
    temprow = tempRng.Row
Else
    Msgbox "Data not found!", vbInformation
End If
```